# How to build sliding block puzzle software for mobiles

Tags: c++, c, mobile

I want to build software of the good old sliding block puzzle for mobile phones could you please guide me how to generate the sliding block puzzle and solving techniques

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Simon Tatham's Portable Puzzle Collection](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/), with full source. You may be able to use its framework directly, and even if you can't you'll find excellent examples of solvers.